# localhost on mac refused to connect

Tags: apache, localhost

I read a lot to solve localhost refused to connect and still not working
I checked the `hotst` which located in 
`/private/etc/hosts`
seems ok (I think)

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

I tried:

```
sudo apachectl configtest' //return Syntax OK
sudo apachectl restart'
```

not working, then I tried this:

```
which apachectl
sudo /usr/local/bin/apachectl configtest //return Syntax OK
sudo /usr/local/bin/apachectl restart
```

also not working !!

Comment: what is the error message from your apache logs?

Comment: @jhnc Cannot serve directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/sites/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: You'll get some helpful hits if you google for "server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive"

Comment: @jhnc i restart the mac and now, the whole localhost directory Forbidden !!

Comment: I suspect your question is more appropriate to https://apple.stackexchange.com